# Printing error for every character read in the string

Tags: java, char

I'm looking not only how to do it, but also how to do it and produce an error message for a character that I don't want. So what I mean is I have the user put in input, then I want to produce an error message if the input the user put didn't have a 0 or a 1. So a 1121 would produce an error, but a 1101 would be fine.

I have this so far and in the shell it prints "error" after every character, even if it's correct.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int n;
System.out.print("Please enter a sequence of 1's and 0's");
String binInput = scan.nextLine();
System.out.println(binaryToDecimal(binInput));

char c;     
for (int j = 0; j < binInput.length(); j++) {   
    c = binInput.charAt(j);
    if (c<0 || c>1){
    System.out.print("Error");}
}

public static int binaryToDecimal(String binString) {
    int size = binString.length();

    if (size == 1) {
        return Integer.parseInt(binString);
    } else {
        return binaryToDecimal(binString.substring(1, size)) + Integer.parseInt(binString.substring(0, 1)) * (int) Math.pow(2, size - 1);
    }

  }
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/48779490/1553851

Comment: This has nothing to do with compiler errors.

Comment: Not a duplicate, different question and different problem

Comment: perhaps printing something useful like System.out.print("Error at index (" + j + ") for character - " + c); will be more helpful than just printing "Error"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O.K. let's see if this code will give you an error. (Please, be sure that you'r input didn't include any 'white spaces'

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n;
    System.out.print("Please enter a sequence of 1's and 0's");
    String binInput = scan.nextLine();
//        System.out.println(binaryToDecimal(binInput));

    char c;
    for (int j = 0; j < binInput.length(); j++) {
        c = binInput.charAt(j);
        if (!(c == '0' || c == '1')) {
            System.out.print("Error");
        }
    }
```

I commented out one statement - it isn't relevant...

Comment: It indeed does still print out 4 error messages, no white spaces at all for my input

Comment: It isn't possible... I'm sure this code is working - I just tried it several times. Please, just copy/paste this code and tell me if it works. If it doesn't work something must be very odd...

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Change the if statement like this

```
if (!(c == '0' || c == '1')){//...
```

It means
**if c isn't character 0 or chararcter 1**

Comment: It prints 4 errors? What is your input for those errors?

Comment: 1101 is what I've been using

Answer (score 1):

c is defined as a char and java allows chars to utilize relational and equivalent operators. The charAt(int) method pulls the specific char out. In this case you should change your if statement to something like this:

```
if(c != '0' && c != '1')
```

Comment: It still is printing 4 error messages when I go through the shell , why is this happening.

Comment: What is your binaryToDecimal(String) method?

Comment: i'll put it in my question

Comment: Sorry forgot my single quotes ( 0 is an int '0' is a char )

Comment: I really just don't understand why no matter what it insists on printing 4 error messages, i've tried it with both tbh

Comment: Try breaking each statement out then.

    `if (c != '0'){ if (c != '1'){ System.out.print("Error");}}`